# Powershell color rendering in Windows Terminal is missing fg/bg color combinations

Tags: powershell

```
foreach ($f in 0..15)
{
  foreach ($b in 0..15)
  {
    write-host -non -ForegroundColor $f -BackgroundColor $b (" {0,2}/{1,2} " -f $f,$b)
  } 
  Write-host 
}
```

I get this result in both linux and windows native console

[image]

However running the same in Windows Terminal shows this

[image]

As can be seen, Windows Terminal intervenes and changes some fg/bg color combinations. Yet all 16 colors are available both as fg and bg color

Is this a general issue or just my setup.
Can it be fixed ?

Thanks

I would expect same result in native console and Windows terminal